# finding a specific number in a number list python

Tags: python, string

For example, I have a list `[25, 64, 67, 81, 90]`.

I want to find the numbers that has the number `6` in them, so the answer will be `64, 67`.

How can I do this?

Comment: I recommend use mathematical way for this , while loop here is needed

Comment: Gotta go fast. Everything posted here is slower than the duplicate link post `%timeit next(i for i in mylist if '6' in str(i))` --> `657 ns ± 1.49 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[x for x in mylist if '6' in str(x)]
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
lst = [25, 64, 67, 81, 90]

print([x for x in lst if '6' in f'{x}'])
```

Output:

```
[64, 67]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the same using filter `result = list(filter(lambda x: '6' in str(x), mylist))`.